# Image height and width issue in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, height, windows-phone

I am new in windows phone ,

Now am doing a sample just trying to show an image in a stack panel.

I want to show the image in its actual height and width. But the actual height and width returns 0.

Actually the image with height of 360px and width of 480 px.

I posted my code below. Pls help.

Thanks.

**MaingPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Name="imagePanel" ></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace ImageResizing
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Image myImage;
    BitmapImage bit;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myImage = new Image();
        Uri uri = new Uri("Penguins.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        bit = new BitmapImage(uri);
        myImage.Source = bit;

        myImage.Width = myImage.ActualWidth; // Returns 0
        myImage.Height = myImage.ActualHeight; // Returns 0

        myImage.Width = bit.PixelWidth;  // Also tried this. It returns 0 too
        myImage.Height = bit.PixelHeight; // Also tried this. It returns 0 too


        myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        imagePanel.Children.Add(myImage);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are zero until AFTER that call to `myImage.Source = bit;`  Prior to that  myImage is just an empty image that doesn't have any content.

Comment: I rearranged the code as u said. But still the height and width returns 0. Just check the editted code above.

Comment: this site: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/520-bitmapimage-and-local-files-.html?start=1 might have some more details relevant to what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

[ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and ActualWidth are the height/width after it has been layed out and rendered. When you are getting it, it has not been drawn yet.

Just get rid of this part and it should work:

```
    myImage.Width = myImage.ActualWidth; // Returns 0
    myImage.Height = myImage.ActualHeight; // Returns 0

    myImage.Width = bit.PixelWidth;  // Also tried this. It returns 0 too
    myImage.Height = bit.PixelHeight; // Also tried this. It returns 0 too
```